How to get Google Fit steps via Health Connect
I am creating an Android app that uses the number of steps obtained from Googlefit.
Due to the discontinuation of the Googlefit API, I have changed the way I obtain the number of steps from Googlefit to be via Health Connect.
Previously, the step count data from the Googlefit app that I could obtain with my app was the total number of steps for entries. However, after changing to obtaining the number of steps through Health Connect, I can only obtain the number of steps displayed in the Googlefit app header.
Is there a way to obtain the number of steps for entries using Health Connect?
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/lH8xr29F.png)
Currently I obtain it using Read raw data.

From what you are describing, you are using the Aggregated data. If you want all the individal records instead you need to read the Raw data see here. Each individual record should be the same as the Google Fit data you see in the bottom of your screenshot.
